# MySQL Stored Procedure response wrong

Tags: mysql

i create one table which is testtable. it has three field id, name and city.

```
create table testtable
(
id int,
name varchar(100),
city varchar(100)
)
```

table reccord is

```
insert into testtable values(1,'Sanjay','Rajkot');
insert into testtable values(2,'Ravi','Ahmedabad');
```

i also create one procedure which name is sp_testtable.

```
DELIMITER //
create procedure sp_testtable
(
    in city varchar(100)
)
BEGIN
    select * from testtable where city = city;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

when i call stored procedure

```
CALL sp_testtable('Rajkot');
```

Result is..

[image]

But i need  like this ...

[image]

I don't know what is wrong...Please tell me..

Answer (score 1):

try changing your variable name to another one.
For example :

```
DELIMITER //
create procedure sp_testtable
(
    in city_name varchar(100)
)
BEGIN
    select * from testtable where city = city_name;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Sql expects that you are comparing the same column, which always result to true.

Answer (score 0):

You always need to distinguish between your parameter and column.

```
DELIMITER //
create procedure sp_testtable
(
    in city_name varchar(100)
)
BEGIN
    select * from testtable where city = city_name;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Alternate approach:

Add table name in your column name : "where testtable.city = city"